# Hosting django to Heroku and getting application error code 10

Tags: python, django, heroku

I think the error may lie in the procfile, but nothing that I try has any luck

I have tried at least a dozen different Procfile changes but nothing seems to work, I have tried changing the path thinking that that may be the problem. I have also tried changing creative_agency.wsgi to creative_agency.wsgi.application and creative_agency.WSGI_APPLICATION as these are how the variable is saves in the settings.py file

log files

```
2019-06-07T16:16:19.567443+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'creative_agency.wsgi'
2019-06-07T16:16:19.567565+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-06-07 16:16:19 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-06-07T16:16:19.592819+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-06-07 16:16:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-06-07T16:16:19.592959+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-06-07 16:16:19 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-06-07T16:16:19.668495+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-06-07T16:16:21.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-06-07T16:17:25.387844+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=westandfaring.herokuapp.com request_id=f7e8183d-83cb-4802-b148-d96012042df
e fwd="68.180.94.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-06-07T16:17:25.626514+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=westandfaring.herokuapp.com request_id=523ff9c5-1c50-4521-b1b3-
a815108f8af7 fwd="68.180.94.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-06-07T16:21:26.403447+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-06-07T16:21:31.577667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn creative_agency.wsgi`
2019-06-07T16:21:33.645817+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap4',
    'webpage.apps.WebpageConfig'
```

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'creative_agency.wsgi.application'
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn creative_agency.wsgi
```

Also, the path to my wsgi file from my main project directory is

```
\Website\creative_agency\creative_agency\wsgi.py
```

Comment: Is your Django code located in a subdirectory of your repository, e.g. in `Website/creative_agency/` (assuming your Git repo is in `Website/`?

Comment: Yes, my git repo is in website/ and my django code is in website/creative_agency/. For example my manage.py file is under website/creative_agency/manage.py

Comment: Okay, that might not work so well. Heroku expects your code's root to be in your repository's root. You can try `web: gunicorn creative_agency.creative_agency.wsgi`, but that depends on the outer `creative_agency` being a valid Python module. The easiest solution is to move everything into the root directory.